# Android three levels recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]

I've been puzzling now on this quite a while.....

In my activity I have a recyclerview with a row adapter (vertical). In each row I have a recyclerview with a panel adapter (horizontal). In each panel I have a recyclerview with an item adapter (vertical).

Everything works fine but when I try to scroll the items the rows are scrolling, not the items.

What I want is that the items will scroll, unless there are not enough items in a panel to scroll, (like in panel B3) then the rows should be scrolling. In case there are enough items in a panel to scroll and I reach top or bottom of the items in a panel, then the rows should start scrolling.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Add screenshots

Comment: It happens when you add verticle scroll inside another verticle or horizontal scroll inside another because of touch interceptor, whether it is a RecyclerView/ ListView/ ScrollView. Your UI is not following standard design pattern. We should always avoid nested scrolling of same direction

Comment: Yes, you are right about this. I have been thinking about this and in most cases I think there won't be many items in a panel so you can't scroll vertically there. Only in case that there are some more items, I had two options. First press the panel to open it full screen to be able to see the remaining items or scrolling. The second options seems better to me. But normally, yes, you are right.

Comment: A third options could be that I increase the height of the panel in case there are more items. Maybe that's a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your layout is inside `NestedScrollView`:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <FrameLayout ...>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           .........
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </FrameLayout >
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I did this for both the recyclerview that holds the rows and the recyclerview that holds the panels. The items are still not scrolling

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```